Seeing perfectly camouflaged objects
Consider a perfectly camouflaged object which perfectly mimicks the texture of its surrounding. One can see the object and its shape only when it moves  - otherwise it is completely invisible.

When it moves too slowly it requires some tricks - looking through the image, or scanning the image - to see the shape. Only when it moves fast enough one can see it quite clearly without effort. You can check this out here.
My question is: Which computer vision systems are able to see the object? Which algorithm do they use? Using background subtraction and contour detection as described in this article on OpenCV obviously would not work. GPT4o is unable to see the object because it only analyzes isolated frames (where the object is invisible).
Has anybody a powerful (recursive) CNN at hand - or whatever type of ANN is well-suited for this kind of video analyis - and can pass this video to it, to see what happens?

Stupid question: why don't you just look at the difference between two consecutive frames ? The area that moves should light up like crazy

Elaborating on my comment: that seems trivial to detect by just looking at the difference between two consecutive frames:
That's one of the primary cues that human perception uses. Changes in stimuli are emphasized over steady state stimulus.
Original:

Frame difference


Either this, or use motion estimation/optical flow across video frames (possibly more robust to real world issues like camera noise and 90% of the pixels not being a perfect white background)

I got the picture, but shouldn't the shape of the difference be the union of the shape of the object before and after?

For moderate amounts of background noise you can always put a threshold on differential detector. The exact definition of "shape" can be whatever you want it to be and the core algorithm can be modified accordingly. Since not all pixel inside the shape will change with every frame, a real world algorithm will need some amount of intelligent averaging. This was just really a quick hack for a proof of concept.


My question is: Which computer vision systems are able to see the object?

Basically anything that is designed to deal with dynamicism. This is optical flow analysis in it's purest form. Basic stuff, as Hilmar illustrates: the simple frame-by-frame difference is enough for excellent detection.
This is especially something that most modern video codec would do (at least of the MPEG family) – probably before the video is even touched by what you think of when you say "computer vision". Here's the motion vectors libx264's MPEG-4 video encoder produces, visualized as little arrows:

If you wanted to know what moved in the video on the machine you'd do the computer vision on, you wouldn't even have to fully decode the video stream; extracting the motion vectors would be enough.

Has anybody a powerful (recursive) CNN at hand - or whatever type of ANN is well-suited for this kind of video analyis - and can pass this video to it, to see what happens?

Don't use a Neural Network for something where an efficient closed form algorithm is known. No need to use an ANN to detect motion – the same units used to calculate the output of an ANN can trivially be used to calculate pixel differences, and that's all that is happening.
Basics first, neural networks as soon as you find something that's not trivially and faster solved with something classic!

Which algorithm do they use?

So, your example is super simple; the motion/object detection for videos is of course much harder, because you get noise, you get multiple conflicting movements, the scene changes overall, lightning differences etc.
A small subset of available and well-documented (including source code) methods for detecting motion based on blocks is documented you'll find in FFmpeg's mestimate filter documentation. They are all based on the same idea: you compare consecutive frames (how many is adjustable), and find blocks within the images that are similar. The variations come from the question how to look for these similarities between thousands of blocks and multiple frames.

I don't want to use ANNs insetad of closed form algorithms but just see how they would do it - to later better understand how biological brains do it. Maybe that's what a super-simple case is good for.

well, that's not how that works. Your ANN would learn to subtract consecutive images. Which is nothing like how the visual system in a brain works. Similarities between contemporary ANNs and the human brain are coincidential, at best. You would need to model the visual system from sensor cell over transport neurons to mixed motion and object detection based on real world firing neurons. This really has nothing to do with CNNs. One could argue that we can reasonably simulate SNNs today, but training these is still either incredibly compute intense (read: can't be done on current hardware)

or very far from what biologists currently think the brain works. You can't really transfer anything you learn from the workings of ANNs to the brain currently.

That's a statement.

@Hans-PeterStricker well it comes from a person who's worked with SNNs for signal processing, if mostly in an assistive role.

Who played the assistive role: you or the SNNs?

I; it was with a colleague who's doing his PhD on spiking neural networks for radio signal processing.
